# Why blocks are not including queued transactions in this private chain

Tags: go-ethereum

I have started two nodes with same `genesis.json` on same machine in a same directory. I followed the following steps:

```
./geth --datadir ./chaindata/ --port 30303 --networkid 15525 --rpc --rpcport 8545--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "web3,eth,personal,net" console
```

and then the second node (ran this command on same machine in same directory):

```
 ./geth --datadir ./chaindata2/ --port 30304 --networkid 15525 --rpc --rpcport 8546 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "web3,eth,personal,net" console
```

**PLESE NOTE THAT THE PORT, RPC PORT , AND DATA DIRECTORY ARE DIFFERENT IN THE TWO**

Then, found the node id of the second one by `admin.nodeInfo` and added it as a peer in the other console with `admin.addpeer`

```
admin.addPeer("enode://f583bdf4e0e56818b920041a0588ba415352fa155935f04fbe287f2e2d111047a2f7e7b15c156d160b2afbbdde46081cf6aa6a73dbdbefddb99a8ebb01e03de3@127.0.0.1:30303")
```

Now Unlocked an account (with pre-allocated balance) and sent transaction:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:"39408873c54f3d8efe67c43532ac3b3b5db7fb7f", to: "11f53eb1649af91da0af06d84700a33919febe9e",value: "250",gasPrice:20 , gas: 21000, nonce: 150 )});
```

But `txpool.status` shows the following:

```
{
  pending: 0,
  queued: 5
}
```

And when I call the `eth.getTransaction("0x5aded5...")`, The block number field is `null`.

Also `txpool.status` on the second node shows

```
{
      pending: 0,
      queued: 0
    }
```

However the blocks are succesfully synchronized, and the mining is successfully done. 
For Information : 
Here is my genesis.json

```
{
   "config": {
      "chainId": 1994,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0
   },
   "difficulty": "4",   // PLEASE NOTE !!!
   "gasLimit": "2000000",
   "alloc": {
      "39408873c54f5b8efe67c4353d4c3b3b5db7fb7f": {
          "balance": "100000000000000000000000"
      },
      "ae13d41d66af2d380c7af6d825ab557eb271ffff": {
          "balance": "120000000000000000000000"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you start the miner?

Comment: Yes.. Could it be a nonce issue... I am using random nonce for this

Comment: For sending transactions*

Comment: Your nonce has to be strictly sequential. Which means that your first nonce has to be 0 and next nonce has to be +1 of your last transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit old but I faced the same issue and resolved it by cleaning my transaction history of metamask.
Following this thread : 
https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/1999

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that I'm supplying arbitrary `nonce` in the `sendTransaction` method. Instead, nonce is decided automatically by geth, and it should be in a sequence. Geth internally maintains the nonce sequence and automatically supplies the next number to it. So you can Omit the nonce in the sendTransaction Method.

`eth.sendTransaction({from:"39408873c54f3d8efe67c43532ac3b3b5db7fb7f", to: "11f53eb1649af91da0af06d84700a33919febe9e",value: "250",gasPrice:20 , gas: 21000 )});`

This should work.